# Spring Hibernate delete object

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I try to remove object from entity by using 'delete' from repository but something doesn't work.

```
@Entity
public class Director implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 15)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 40)
    private String surname;

    @Column(length = 40,unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 12)
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne
    private School school;

    public School getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DirectorRepository extends CrudRepository<Director, Long> {

    Director findOneByEmail(String email);

}
```

Method from Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "deleteDirector", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String delpost(@ModelAttribute Director director) {

        try {
            directorRepository.delete(director.getId());
            return "deleteDirectorSuccess-view";
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        return "deleteDirectorError-view";
    }
```

I don't know what happens there because it returns `deleteDirectorSuccess-view` but doesn't delete this object from database (Im sure that id is correct, I tried put `directorRepository.delete(ID_FROM_DATABASE_AS_LONG);` but there is the same problem.
If I put script in database like:

```
DELETE FROM public.director
 WHERE id=ID_FROM_DATABASE;
```

it works, another method in controller where I save object to database by:

```
directorRepository.save(director);
```

works perfectly too.

I have no idea how to check why it's wrong and how to solve my problem.

Comment: Not sure why save is working. Have you used @Transactional annotation anywhere?

Comment: No, I have not @Transactional in my project

Comment: try to use it on delPost method and see if it works.

Comment: Try committing the transaction and flushing your changes.

Comment: We usually put stuff like log.error("sometext", e) in catch blocks, so that when some exception occurs we are informed. You should try that maybe some e.printStackTrace() would be a good start

Comment: @RC. I know but there is not any exception, it just returns success view

Comment: ¿Are you managing the transactionallity or delegating to the container? Try to call directorRepository.save(director) before the delete sentence. Does it create the new director?

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez director has only id but if I create Director d = new Director() , then set email (because can not be nullable) I can use save.(d) and  it works (add new director to database)

Comment: So if you call save and delete **inside the same method** the insert is commited?

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "deleteDirector", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional
public String delpost(@ModelAttribute Director director) {

    try {
        Director d = directorRepository.findOne(director.getId());
        directorRepository.delete(d);
        return "deleteDirectorSuccess-view";
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    return "deleteDirectorError-view";
}
```

I think entity is need to managed by persistence layer before doing anything. But that does not explains why save is working.